# Web.config value in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-config

i want to acess  the web config value in javascript

config entry:

```
<add key ="RootPath" value ="C:\Test" />
```

javascript code:

```
  var v1 = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"].ToString() %>'
```

The output that i am getting is

```
 C:Test
```

but what i want is C:\Test

Any idea how to acheive this ?

Comment: as side note: I would really not call directly the ConfigurationManager from JavaScript. you could have that value rendered in an hidden field or worst case in a public static method of the page you access the ConfigurationManager and from JavaScript you call the public method, it starts getting nasty having client code reading config file directly, in my opinion...

Comment: if you are using .net 4.0 you can use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"].ToString().Replace(@"\", @"\\")
```

Comment: And then hope there isn't a `'` in the file name :-) You should escape the `'` and the `"` (both of them just to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this

```
var defaults = {inactivity: <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Inactivity"] %> }
```

Refer to the [Read Configuration settings from javascript](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=131). If you are getting the config value like

```
C:\Test
```

change the config entry to `C:\\Test` and in C# especially in paths the `\\` will be automatically converted in to `\` because slash will be escaped by using escape sequence, because anything that begins with a backslash ('\') is termed as escape sequence in C#.

Comment: You need to do the addslashes bit in your server-side code not javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var v1 = '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"].Replace(@"\",@"\\") %>'
```

ToString() is excess

Answer (score 0):

**if you adding this**

```
<add key ="RootPath" value ="C:\\Test" />
```

then you will retrive like `"C:\Test"`.
**Its behavior of .net.**